# Why does the filtering not work as expects in .rdl file?

Tags: reporting-services, filtering, rdl

The dataset defined in my .rdl file returns rows with the some special column. I need to display two tables based on this dataset. In first table i need to display the rows which have a null value in that special column. In second table below I want to display the rows which don't have a null values in that special column. For achieving this i'm using filter section of group properties for each table.

Here is the filter for table1:

`IsNothing(Fields!Parent_F_registr_Pts.Value) = true`

And here is the filter for table2:

`IsNothing(Fields!Parent_F_registr_Pts.Value) = false`

When i'm starting the report I see rows in the table1 but no rows in the table2. Why is it so and how should i fix the issue?

Comment: Do you see all rows in table 1 or just the rows you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the tablix filter set the following:

Expression: =IsNothing(Fields!Parent_F_registr_Pts.Value)

Expression Type: Boolean

Operator: =

Value: True for null values / False for not null values

Alternatives:

1. Conditional visibility on rows using your expression
2. Instead of two seperate tablix, group using the expression